# Two routers with DHCP?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

My current network setup is like this:

SKY Netgear Wireless Router (Downstairs) ----> Homeplug ----> DG834N Netgear Wireless Router (Upstairs)

What I would like is to have DHCP enabled on both routers, for the upstairs connections to have their own ip address range and DNS Servers while the Downstairs connections to have another set.

I have changed the DHCP settings etc. around but when it comes to wireless connections being made, it just doesn't work.

Can anyone help me

Comment: Do the networks work properly before trying to use wireless? Do your wireless devices discover the wireless networks at all? Have you enabled wireless?

Comment: Wireless is enabled, the devices can see the wireless network, it's just that I'm not trying to use my first router as a gateway, more as a central hub which all my traffic is routed to after being routed through the upstairs router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either have one router serving DHCP and create a "bridge" to the other one. This means all devices would get their IP address from one router.

The other method would be having DHCP enabled on both routers, just pushing different IP ranges, for example the first on an IP of 192.168.2.1 and pushing 192.168.2.2 through to 100, and the second on an IP of 192.168.2.101 and pushing 192.168.2.102 through 192.168.2.200. Not sure how well this would work though. Or you could even do a different subnet, so upstars is 192.168.2.x and downstairs is 192.168.3.x.

Comment: It would be best to use different subnets when using two routers with DHCP, and even then, you might get issues. What I see commonly in that situation is that a computer that sends out a request will be assigned an IP by the first DHCP server that responds to the handshake, though it won't necessarily be on the network it was intended. Now if it doesn't matter which gateway the traffic travels out of, this isn't terribly important, but it still would be much simpler in all regards to have just one DHCP server and to use the other router simply as an access point.